# MS Access 365 When selecting Lookup Wizard, datatype is changed autmatically to Number

Tags: database-design, ms-access, datatypes

I want to create a relationship between my Contacts table & Ref_State table.

Contacts table has field called State/Region which I want to make Data Type = Lookup Wizard
Ref_State has fields ID (autonum), StateDescription(short text), & StateAbbreviation(short text).

When I complete the lookup wizard and have Referential Integrity, Cascade Update & Cascade delete selected, the Data Type for State/Region in the Contacts table is changed to "Number". I'm confused why it does this and need to know if this is an error or normal for all lookup data types to be changed to something other than what was intended with no way to alter the datatype. Is it displaying Number because the Primary Key in the Ref_State is ID which is an auto number, and hence the Contacts field State/Region displays a Number Datatype? But When looking at data view and adding entries to the table, the StateDescription field is being displayed, not the ID.   I'm really lost.

I get this message when I try complete the Lookup Wizard

> Some data may be lost.
>   The size of one or more fields has been changed to a shorter size. If data is lost, validation rules may be violated as a result. Do you want to continue anyway?

I took a database class in college and am familiar with basic concepts, but MS Access is making this a nightmare for me to design.

Comment: I believe this is the same problem I am having. In Table1, the field I am looking up is "short text." In Table2, the lookup defaults to Number Subtype "Whole number (no decimal places)" and I am unable to change it to a "Short Text" type. When looking at data in Table2, it shows the text from Table1 lookup just fine. It only becomes a problem when I want to use the field in Table2 to create a string in another cell, at which point it being a Number doesn't let me combine it with another string.

Comment: A workaround (which I can't figure out) would be to be able to convert the number to the appropriate text within the expression that is building the string. Something like `FieldText1 + FieldText2 + Table1.FieldText(FieldLookup)`. But I cannot even figure out how to convert the number to a string in an Access App (there is no `CStr()` function available).